# Wait for Rx observer to complete without using lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I have an application running an observable interval with multiple observers. Every 0.5s the interval loads some XML data from a web server, then the observers do some application specific processing on a background thread. Once the data isn't needed anymore, the subscriptions and the interval observable get disposed, so observer's OnNext/OnCompleted/OnError won't be called anymore. So far so good.

My problem: In some rare cases it is possible, that after calling Dispose my observer's OnNext method is still running! Before proceeding to further operations after disposing, I would like to ensure that OnNext has been completed.

My current solution: I've introduced a locker field in my observer class (see code). After disposing I try to acquire a lock and continue only after the lock has been acquired. While this solution works (?), it somehow just feels wrong to me.

Question: Is there a more elegant, more "Rx Way" to solve this problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RxExperimental
{
    internal sealed class MyXmlDataFromWeb
    {
        public string SomeXmlDataFromWeb { get; set; }
    }

    internal sealed class MyObserver : IObserver<MyXmlDataFromWeb>
    {
        private readonly object _locker = new object();
        private readonly string _observerName;

        public MyObserver(string observerName) {
            this._observerName = observerName;
        }

        public object Locker {
            get { return this._locker; }
        }

        public void OnCompleted() {
            lock (this._locker) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: Completed.", this._observerName);
            }
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error) {
            lock (this._locker) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: An error occured: {1}", this._observerName, error.Message);
            }
        }

        public void OnNext(MyXmlDataFromWeb value) {
            lock (this._locker) {
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: OnNext running on thread {1}... ", this._observerName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: XML received: {1}", this._observerName, value.SomeXmlDataFromWeb);
                Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate some long running operation
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}: OnNext running on thread {1}... Done.", this._observerName, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        }
    }

    internal sealed class Program
    {
        private static void Main() {
            const int interval = 500;
            //
            var dataSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval), NewThreadScheduler.Default).Select(_ => {
                var data = new MyXmlDataFromWeb {
                    SomeXmlDataFromWeb = String.Format("<timestamp>{0:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss:fff}</timestamp>", DateTime.Now)
                };
                return data;
            }).Publish();
            //
            var observer1 = new MyObserver("Observer 1");
            var observer2 = new MyObserver("Observer 2");
            //
            var subscription1 = dataSource.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(observer1);
            var subscription2 = dataSource.ObserveOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default).Subscribe(observer2);
            //
            var connection = dataSource.Connect();
            //
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            //
            subscription1.Dispose();
            subscription2.Dispose();
            connection.Dispose();
            //
            lock (observer1.Locker) {
                Console.WriteLine("Observer 1 completed.");
            }
            lock (observer2.Locker) {
                Console.WriteLine("Observer 2 completed.");
            }
            //
            Console.WriteLine("Can only be executed, after all observers completed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that you are not working in the spirit of Rx, if you are performing long blocking work in your OnNext callback. As Rx is effectively  a pipeline of callbacks, you will be blocking your source producer. You may want to either consider a message passing design instead, or look at making your OnNext handlers introduce another layer of asynchrony (see Nested Observable Sequences)

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest you do not implement IObserver<T> (or for that matter IObservable<T>) interfaces. Instead, create queries with the operators.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there's a more Rx-way of doing this.

The first observation is that unsubscribing from an observable stream is essentially independent from what is currently happening within the observer.  There's not really any feedback.  Since you have the requirement that you know definitively when the observations have ended, you need to model this into your observable stream.  In other words, instead of unsubscribing from the stream, you should *complete* the stream so you will be able to observe the `OnComplete` event.  In your case, you can use `TakeUntil` to end the observable instead of unsubscribing from it.

The second observation is that your main program needs to observe when your "observer" finishes its work.  But since you made your "observer" an actual `IObservable`, you don't really have a way to do this.  This is a common source of confusion I see when people first start using Rx.  If you model your "observer" as just another link in the observable chain, then your main program can observer.  Specifically, your "observer" is nothing more than a mapping operation (with side effects) that maps incoming Xml data into "done" messages.

So if you refactor your code, you can get what you want...

```
public class MyObserver
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public MyObserver(string name) { _name = name; }

    public IObservable<Unit> Handle(IObservable<MyXmlDataFromWeb source)
    {
        return source.Select(value =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000); // simulate work
            return Unit.Default;
        });
    }
}

// main
var endSignal = new Subject<Unit>();
var dataSource = Observable
    .Interval(...)
    .Select(...)
    .TakeUntil(endSignal)
    .Publish();
var observer1 = new MyObserver("Observer 1");
var observer2 = new MyObserver("Observer 2");
var results1 = observer1.Handle(dataSource.ObserveOn(...));
var results2 = observer2.Handle(dataSource.ObserveOn(...));
// since you just want to know when they are all done
// just merge them.
// use ToTask() to subscribe them and collect the results
// as a Task
var processingDone = results1.Merge(results2).Count().ToTask();

dataSource.Connect();

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel ...");
Console.ReadLine();

// end the stream
endSignal.OnNext(Unit.Default);

// wait for the processing to complete.
// use await, or Task.Result
var numProcessed = await processingDone;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. However, this approach leaves a few questions unanswered:

1. While doing the actual work in MyOberver's Handle method could replace the onNext handler, how is this approach supposed to handle onError and onCompleted events? And how would you ensure that the work done by onError/onCompleted is actually completed before proceeding to further operations after canceling the interval? Of course I could add a disposable subscription, but then I have the same problem as before. ;-)

Comment: 2. Doing the actual work in MyObserver's Handle method has one disadvantage: processingDone.Wait() waits until all messages in the sequence have been processed. This behavior isn't desired! I expect it to ignore/dispose all outstanding messages (if any) immediately after canceling the interval (and wait only for completion of the currently running onNext/onError/onCompleted). My initial approach (with lock) achieves this behavior by disposing the subscriptions.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1 - Have `MyObserver` append more operators after the `Select`.  There are many choices depending on your exact requirements.  [.Do()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229830(v=vs.103).aspx) is a good place to start looking.  Rx will guarantee the operations complete before `processingDone` task completes.

Comment: 2 - when you signal `endSignal`, this causes `TakeUntil(endSignal)` to end the input stream and stop processing any new messages.  Only the current message will finish processing.  Rx already guarantees only one message at a time.  Messages don't "build up" unless you specifically apply an operator like `Buffer` or `ObserveOn`, and even then you can place your `TakeUntil` operator *after* such buffering operations to still ensure you end the stream and throw away buffered requests.